# Powershell loop iteration count

Tags: powershell, loops, iteration

The purpose of the scripts is to catch wrong logins to Elasticsearch, and gave the opportunity to retry entering a password. The idea was to count loop iteration by adding `i++` after `$result = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Credential $credential` step, but it turned out that `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` process is ignored in case it's located in `try{}` section, so i moved loop counts into `finally {$i++}` section, but the cons is that the last `Attempt 5` does not pass the condition `while ($i -lt 6)` cuz it is `5+1` in `finally {$i++}` section.

```
$elasticsearch_pass = Read-Host "Enter ELASTICSEARCH password"
$uri = "https://${elasticsearch_ip}:9200"
$user = "static_user"
$i = 1
while ($i -lt 6) {
        try {       
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan `n ("Trying to connect to elasticsearch. Attempt $i")
        $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $elasticsearch_pass -AsPlainText -Force
        $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)     
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Credential $credential
            if ($result.tagline -eq 'You Know, for Search') {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green `n ("Connection to elasticsearch {0} established..." -f $elasticsearch_ip)
                break
            }
        } 
        catch {
          Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_
          if ("$_" -eq "Unauthorized") {
            $elasticsearch_pass = Read-Host `n "Wrong elasticsearch password! Pls enter correct one"
          }
        }
        finally {$i++} 
    }
```

What is the best approach to set a static loop iteration count and execute the last Attempt?

Comment: A [For](https://ss64.com/ps/for.html) loop seems to be a reasonable alternative to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why use While, if an interation var is needed the usual solution is a traditional for:

```
$uri = "https://${elasticsearch_ip}:9200"
$user = "static_user"
$i = 1
$maxTry = 5

For( $i = 1; $i -le $maxTry; ++$i )
{
    try {       
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan `n ("Trying to connect to elasticsearch. Attempt $i of $maxtry ")
        $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $elasticsearch_pass -AsPlainText -Force
        $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)     
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Credential $credential
            if ($result.tagline -eq 'You Know, for Search') {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green `n ("Connection to elasticsearch {0} established..." -f $elasticsearch_ip)
                break
            }
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
        if ($_.Exception.Message -match "Unauthorized") {
        }
    }
}
```

In either case I don't think you need to do the ++$i in the finally block, you could just do in the catch and continue.  However the for loop allows you to do it at the right point in each iteration without the confusion.

Also added $maxTry gives a slightly better echo...

Since this is interactive I changed some of the catch block to echo a little more cleanly.

Also moved the Read-Host into the loop.  and changed the language a little.  though there are a couple of ways to do that...

Comment: the problem is that $elasticsearch_pass is given in ```Catch``` section and execution are in ```try``` section witch is the next iteration, so no matter using ```While```  or ```For```, the last try will not work.

Comment: I don't understand, but rereading your question again... The For loop will get the iterations correct, exactly 5 attempts.  If you want Invoke-WebRequest to trigger the catch you probably need to use `-ErrorAction Stop` .  That will turn non-termination errors into termination to trigger the catch.

Else you can just assign the result to a variable as you had been doing then manually check it.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: ```-ErrorAction``` process is ignored if it located it ```try``` section, also it was described in the head of the question. For some reason you missed ```$elasticsearch_pass = Read-Host `n "Wrong elasticsearch password! Pls enter correct one"``` procedure in your example.

Comment: In ```catch``` section I add ```$i -le 4``` check which solve my issue, ```("$_" -match "Unauthorized" -and $i -le 4) {```